# consume SOAP xml using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, soap

I am trying to do this, for an App with Jquery and asp.net c# this is my web method and the ajax code calling it, but it keeps bring out 'error' under the error function

```
//c# code
[WebMethod]
public int Add(int x, int y)
{
  return x + y;
}

var webServiceURL = 'http://local_server/Service1.asmx?op=Add';

    var soapMessage = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><Add xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><x>6</x><y>5</y></Add></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>';

            function CallService() {

                $.ajax({
                    url: webServiceURL,
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    data: soapMessage,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    error: OnError
                });
                return false;
            }


            function OnSuccess(data, status) {
                alert(data.d);
            }

            function OnError(request, status, error) {
                alert('error');
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                jQuery.support.cors = true;
            });
```

Comment: why aren't you inspecting the arguments instead of displaying a hard coded string in the callback? Look at actual request in browser console network tab for more dteails also

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for your reply but even when i have parameters its still the same 'Error' message i get

Comment: @charlietfl when i check the webconsole network tab i see "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed" for the webservice call, but typing the url into the browser it goes through

Comment: so this is a cross domain call? If you don't control API domain there are numerous workarounds. Research the terms `CORS` and `Same Origin Policy`

Comment: Thanks for your reply i got around the "Method not allowed" it now shows "[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 15ms]" but yet i still get an 'Error' alert.